# A tool that can insert a line (f.e. console.log) before and after every block scope of a file or of multiple files?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious to know if one exists.

I think it'd be handy for debugging. f.e. We could add a unique `console.log` statement before and after each block scope, then we'd be able to see the last output in a program to find which block scope has the crashing error.

Comment: C'mon man, you're setting a bad example for others. 10k+ rep and you're asking for tool recommendations? You know that's off-topic.

Comment: Doesn't the stack trace already tell which line caused the error?

Comment: @Juhana Yes, but sometimes the error isn't an exception, it can simply be mis=behaving app with programmer error (not logic error, not runtime exception, but no exception at all). If a UI gets stuck in some weird place, maybe it would help to see the code path (with console messages) to find the cause.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks, I up-voted your comment!  I guess we all have some lazy in us. LOL. :} But, I *did* search first, and I couldn't find any such tool. By the way, is there a better place to ask such a question?

Comment: The closest in the SE network would probably be http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ but check their requirements first.

Answer (score 0):

That actually **Doesn't exist.**

But you can take advantage of `console.group` and `console.groupCollapsed` to group any number of `console.log` statements, here is an example :

```
console.group('User');
  console.log('initialization');
  console.log('event registrations');
console.groupEnd('User');
```

Here is a screenshot picture:

[image]

Comment: If you down vote please, add a comment why you've done so !

Comment: If it is useful please consider accepting the answer!.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't exist I think. But you can ofcourse try something out that does the same.  `Console.Group` will do the trick.